# Create matrix in a loop with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, iteration

I would like to build up a numpy matrix using rows I get in a loop. But how do I initialize the matrix? If I write

```
A = []
A = numpy.vstack((A, [1, 2]))
```

I get

ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

What's the best practice for this?

NOTE: I do not know the number of rows in advance. The number of columns is known.

Comment: Don't edit the question to invalidate existing answers. If you have another question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 6):

**Unknown number of rows**

One way is to form a list of lists, and then convert to a `numpy` array in one operation:

```
final = []

# x is some generator
for item in x:
    final.append(x)

A = np.array(x)
```

Or, more elegantly, given a generator `x`:

```
A = np.array(list(x))
```

This solution is time-efficient but memory-inefficient.

**Known number of rows**

Append operations on `numpy` arrays are expensive and not recommended. If you know the size of the final array in advance, you can instantiate an empty (or zero) array of your desired size, and then fill it with values. For example:

```
A = np.zeros((10, 2))
A[0] = [1, 2]
```

Or in a loop, with a trivial assignment to demonstrate syntax:

```
A = np.zeros((2, 2))

# in reality, x will be some generator whose length you know in advance
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

for idx, item in enumerate(x):
    A[idx] = item

print(A)

array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])
```

Comment: You've put effort into answering this question. The OP is not allowed to edit the original question to invalidate this answer. If it is edited, please raise a mod flag.